# how to use custom dataset with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a GAN in Tensorflow, and i have it working with the `fashion_mnist` dataset.
but i can't seem to get my own data in the right format, it keeps giving bugs at line 16.

This is the original code for making the dataset, i have tried 3-4 times already using different methods but the data is always in the wrong format.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

tf.random.set_seed(1)

print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")))


from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist

(train_ds, train_label), (test_ds, test_label) = fashion_mnist.load_data()


import numpy as np

dataset = np.concatenate([train_ds, test_ds], axis=0)
dataset = np.expand_dims(dataset, -1).astype("float32") / 255


BATCH_SIZE = 64

dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing images from local folder instead of using Keras/Tensorflow dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72765150/importing-images-from-local-folder-instead-of-using-keras-tensorflow-dataset/)

Comment: Which one is line 16? And what errors do you get?